# Why isn't document.cookie returning all cookies on Firefox 69?

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

When calling `document.cookie` in the Firefox 69 console, it's not returning all cookies. The cookies were set by `my.site` and I'm calling `document.cookie` on `my.site/test`.

I am expecting to see the 'impex_mem' and 'impex_user' cookies.

[image]

Oddly, after I refresh the page once, `document.cookie` does return 'impex_mem' and 'impex_user' cookies.

When testing this on Chrome, Safari, and Edge, `document.cookie` does return the impex_user and impex_mem cookies.

Thanks

Comment: You've blocked out the `domain` column, so it's a little hard to say, but I'd imagine that `SameSite` column being `Strict` for those cookies is relevant. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SameSite

Comment: Please post your code showing how you set the cookies, and how you get the cookies.  Without that it's just guess work.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks, that did the trick. I noticed they were set to samesite, but didn't think it would make a difference since other browsers were able to read them. I guess Firefox handles cookies differently. 

You can post it as an answers and I'll accept it ceejayoz

Answer (score 0):

Quick Answer: Change Cookie from `SameSite=Strict` to `SameSite=Lax`

#### Explanation

I have noticed the same issue with Firefox. It appears that when receiving a `SameSite=Strict` cookie on a request, Javascript (`document.cookie`) is not able to read it. However, on a refresh, this works as expected.

If you are in control of your own cookies, change SameSite to *Lax* rather than *Strict*.

Chrome and IE/Edge work fine with Strict but Firefox doesn't (not tried on Safari).